# How to create nested structure in redis using python?

Tags: python, redis, redis-py

```
redis = {}
        redis['A'] = {}
        redis['A']['1'] = value1
        redis['A']['2'] = value2
        redis['A']['3'] = value3
```

I need to make above structure in redis using python.
I have established connection using redis-py client in python like this:

```
_connection = redis.StrictRedis(host='localhost', port=6379, db=0)
```

please let me know how to create , store and get values in redis using python?

Comment: Please show us what you have tried.

Comment: `redis = { 'A' : { '1' : value1, '2' : value2, '3' : value3}}`?

Answer (score 0):

It's important to know that Redis does not support arbitrarily nested data structures natively. Instead, it has a few (maps, lists, queues). Anything more sophisticated, you need to decompose into these structures.

Now if you only care about two levels of nesting, then you can use `HMAP` support. See [`HSET`](https://redis.io/commands/hset) and [`HGET`](https://redis.io/commands/hget)

In your example, the HMAP's name would be `'A'`, and `1`, `2`, and `3` would be keys.

Also note that Redis only supports binary and string key/values. So you would need to decide whether you are going to store keys in `str(x)` form, or encode in binary (`x.to_bytes(4, byteorder = 'big'`)

I leave it to you to figure out how to map this to the python client's APIs -- they tend to match the logical operations faithfully. For example,

```
_connection.hget('A', '1')
```